# How to merge partitions with one partition is a Linux root partition

Tags: partitioning, merge

I have a Linux hard drive with two partitions:

```
/dev/sdb1           16126 234437409 234421284 111,8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5           16128 161870939 161854812  77,2G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb6  *    161871003 234437409  72566407  34,6G 83 Linux
```

Both sdb5 and sdb6 are already filled with data.

How do I safely merge those two partitions without loosing data and OS?

Comment: I would copy the data onto two physically independent backup devices and verify them.  Then use gparted to delete both partitions and create a new one in the space.  Then copy your data back.

Comment: If you have enough free space on sdb5 to hold all of the data from sdb6, then copy over the data, then use gparted to delete sdb6 and extend sdb5. If there's not enough room on sdb5, then copy sdb6 data off to a flash drive, use gparted to delete sdb6, extend sdb5, and then restore the data from the flash drive.

Comment: @heynnema : is it gonna change if sdb6 is my root directory? Sorry if I didn't mention this before.

Comment: Yes it will. Then copy off sdb5 to an external HDD or flash drive, use gparted to delete sdb5, and extend sdb6, and copy back the data from the flash drive. Make sure that you have a good external backup of sdb6 just in case something goes wrong. Basically you can do what @OrganicMarble suggested earlier.